# Changing order output, using if or something that

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *,`kills`-`deaths` as x FROM `users` ORDER BY `x` DESC LIMIT 0,50;
```

table:

```
user|kills|deaths
a   | 10  | 9
b   | 11  | 9
c   | 0   | 0
d   | 0   | 0
e   | 0   | 0
f   | 1   | 5
```

the output will be:

```
b | 2
a | 1
c | 0
d | 0
e | 0
f | -4
```

i need output like this:

```
b | 2
a | 1
f | -4
c | 0
d | 0
e | 0
```

because user is active and he have kills and deaths, other users are inactive, so they go to bottom.

How to do it ?

Comment: So How do you know they are Active?

Comment: If the other users are inactive, they should probably have `null` kills/deaths - this is distinct from 0.  Which should also sort as you want, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, kills-deaths as x 
FROM users 
ORDER BY x = 0, x DESC LIMIT 0,50;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/168bde/2)

Comment: +1 for the SqlFiddle. Fiddles are always helpful in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your measure for activity to the `order by` clause.

```
SELECT *, (kills-deaths) as x 
FROM users 
ORDER BY ((kills+deaths) <> 0), x DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

My usual quick solution is using a group by

```
SELECT user,`kills`-`deaths` as x 
FROM `users` 
group by user 
ORDER BY `x` DESC 
LIMIT 0,50;
```

Here you can also

```
SELECT user,`kills`-`deaths` as x 
FROM `users` 
ORDER BY `kills`-`deaths` DESC 
LIMIT 0,50;
```

I use group by to make any computation to be taking place only in one place and is consistent.